# Showing a function is integrable using Riemann's criterion

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

> Define $f:[0,2] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1, &\text{if} \: x \neq 1 \\ -1, &\text{if} \: x=1\end{cases}.$$ Using Riemann's criterion, prove that $f$ is integrable on $[0,2]$.

Now, I think I am right in saying that Riemann's criterion is as follows:

> A bounded function $f$ is integrable if and only if $\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists$ a partition $P$ such that $$U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\varepsilon.$$

First of all I defined the partition $P$ to be $$P=\{0,1-\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon,2\}.$$ I was also thinking of defining $P$ to be $$P_n=\left\{ \frac kn: k=0,1,\dots,2n \right\}$$ and so $1 \in P_n$ $\forall n$.

What would be the best approach for a question like this?

Comment: They both work... almost (you need $1\pm \varepsilon/2$). The best one is the one _you_ feel most comfortable using to convey your ideas.

Comment: That's true. The $P=\{0,1-\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon,2\}$ option seems more natural as it has the $\varepsilon$'s included straight away.

Comment: Was that correction made because you will come out with $<2\varepsilon$? Which wouldn't necessarily matter, as $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary.

Comment: Technically, it _does_ matter, since with your partition you get $U-L=2\varepsilon\not <\varepsilon$. You need to find a partition that satisfies $U-L<\varepsilon$ in order to fulfill the hypothesis of your theorem (actually, for that, you need to be _narrower_ than $\pm\varepsilon/2$, since we're after strict inequalities). It's only details, but some times details are more important than they are in this case.

Answer (score 1):

$x=1$ is the only point of discontinuity. Take a small interval around $x=1$, and then it doesnt matter what you do everywhere else, just cover it in the simplest way possible. The only contribution will be from the ivterval about $x=1$.